# How to use dataview inside a dynamic SQL query as an alternative for SQL table?

Tags: c#, linq, dataview

I want to use a dataview result as a table inside a dynamic sql query.

This is the dataview

```
DataTable allvalues = DataUtility.GetDataTable("Select * from "'+GetView(ID)+'");
           EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = from props in allvalues.AsEnumerable()
select props;

 DataView propview = query.AsDataView();
```

Here is the dynamic sql query.

```
sqlsub="SELECT  isnull(Sum(props)/count(prop),0) As avgprops,
isnull((Sum(CASE grade WHEN 'A' THEN 3 WHEN 'B' THEN 2 WHEN 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))/(count(props)),0) as Propclass  FROM '"+propview+"'   WHERE props in ("+PropIds+")";
```

Is it possible to use the dataview in the from clause of dynamic SQL query?

Comment: If you connect to database using Entity.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/add-new-connections?view=vs-2017

Comment: no am not using entity

Comment: I know.  You asked how to do a dynamic query and I'm saying to switch to Entity.

Comment: okay, Let me try that.

Comment: that won't work, the initial dataview I retrieve is dynamic in nature. The value of the ID in the first query changes every time. My actual intention is to save time by not going for DB calls each time the data is wanted from the table, instead, the data could be retrieved from the dataview avoiding DB calls

Comment: Why not?  The dataview should be looking at the columns returned from the query.  I can build a dynamic datatable from the linq results just like you did with the GetDataTable() method.

Comment: So how do I map the entity to the view which changes dynamically with the ID passed?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sorting-with-dataview-linq-to-dataset